# Why a function accepts an object reference but rejects it when inserting the same object as a literal object?

Tags: typescript

I'm reading the book [Programming TypeScript by Boris Cherny](https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/programming-typescript/9781492037644/) (pg. 77) and got confused about an example.

Why doesn't TS complain when calling `MapNode` with the object `c` and it does when using the object literal `{ value: "c", children: [b] }`.

Essentially, both have the same object shape. Why TS allows one and not the other?

Thanks!

```
type TreeNode = {
  value: string
}

type LeafNode = TreeNode & {
  isLeaf: true
}

type InnerNode = TreeNode & {
  children: [TreeNode] | [TreeNode, TreeNode]
}

let a: TreeNode = { value: "a" }
let b: LeafNode = { value: "b", isLeaf: true }
let c: InnerNode = { value: "c", children: [b] }

// Ok
let c1 = mapNode(c, _ => _.toUpperCase())

// Argument of type '{ value: string; children: LeafNode[]; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'TreeNode'.
// Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'children' does not exist in type 'TreeNode'.(2345)
let c2 = mapNode({ value: "c", children: [b] }, _ => _.toUpperCase())

function mapNode(a: TreeNode, fn: (b: string) => string) {
  // ...
}
```